# Content Query Web Part does not appear in add a web part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, content-query-web-part

I have activated "SharePoint Server Publishing", but when i add a web part to a page i miss Content Rollup and the Content Query Web Part. It does not appear!

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more information about your issue:

1. What’s the version of SharePoint you use? SharePoint Online or On-premises?
2. What’s the permission of the account you want to add the web part? Make sure the user is allowed to customize the page.
3. Make sure you have activated “SharePoint Server Enterprise Site collection features” in site level and site collection level.

Comment: 3 is a good point, it always happens to me.